# Como mudar a cor de uma curva quando os valores aumentam?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Eu tenho um conjunto de dados. Por vezes, alguns valores aumentam em comparação com os anteriores.

```
resultsCos = [(0, 0.4235497237569061), (0.005, 0.4235497237569061), (0.01, 0.4238950276243094), (0.015, 0.42382596685082874), (0.02, 0.42375690607734806), (0.025, 0.42230662983425415), (0.03, 0.4210635359116022), (0.035, 0.41671270718232045), (0.04, 0.40835635359116024), (0.045, 0.3966850828729282), (0.05, 0.3770027624309392), (0.055, 0.3546270718232044), (0.1, 0.25041436464088396), (0.06, 0.3301795580110497), (0.065, 0.30738950276243093), (0.07, 0.2892955801104972), (0.075, 0.27603591160220997), (0.08, 0.2653314917127072), (0.09, 0.2553867403314917)]
```

Eu consegui fazer um gráfico com o seguinte código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# plot results Cosinus similarity
target = resultsCos
zip(*target)
plt.scatter(*zip(*target))
plt.xlabel('treshold/distance')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy of cosine according to the distance')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas nós realmente não percebemos quando houve uma melhora, e eu gostaria de destacar isso.

Como mudar a cor de uma curva quando os valores aumentam? E devolvê-los à cor original quando eles não aumentam?

Qual é o método para mudar a cor de acordo com o valor anterior?

Comment: Você pode analisar a derivada da sua função. Quando a derivada for positiva, foi possui crescimento nos dados; se negativa, diminuição e, quando nula, os dados permaneceram inalterados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar os dados como entrada de cores e mudar o [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) do gráfico.
Em exemplo abaixo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Meus dados randomicos
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

#Mude o COLORMAP aqui
plt.cool()
plt.scatter(x, y,c=y)
```

Tendo como resultado:

[image: Usando Cool colormap]

Além disso, você pode ter analises mais elaboradas para definir a cor dos pontos, tal qual foi sugerido no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325271/como-mudar-a-cor-de-uma-curva-quando-os-valores-aumentam#comment658643_325271). Porém, o processo final de mudança de cores sera feito provavelmente usando o `colormap` ou então plotando os pontos individualmente e trocando a cor conforme o seu valor (ou deixando como está, dependendo do que você quer mostrar). Os dois podem tem o mesmo efeito se aplicados corretamente.